# GCC Compiler gives warning for a static variable defined and used

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, static-variables

Consider the sample code below :

**File1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

static int x = 6;                          // line 3

int main()
{
   int x = 10;                             // line 7
   {
      extern int x;                        // line 9
      x = x + 5;
      std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
   }
}
```

The external declaration in line 9 causes `x` in the following lines to refer to the static `x` (defined in line 3) instead of the automatic `x` (defined in line 7). But I get the following compiler warning:

> File1.cpp:3: warning: 'x' defined but not used

Even with this warning, I get the expected output which is `x = 11`, which is 5 added to the value of the static variable `x`.

Why is the compiler giving the above warning? I am using GCC version `g++ (GCC) 3.4.6`.

Comment: That's a really old GCC version. Lots has been fixed since then. Have you tried a modern version as well?

Comment: @ tofutim : Yes x = 10 is not used. That is certain. Ok may be i am using an old compiler!

Comment: My g++ 4.6 gives the same error.

Comment: If you take out "int x = 10" it will work.

Comment: If you write "int y = 10" it will work too. Maybe the compiler is just confused which 'x' to take since you define it twice.

Comment: If you take out the parenthesis, it says:

file1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file1.cpp:11:14: error: declaration of ‘int x’
file1.cpp:9:6: error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘int x’ - is this for some exam?

Comment: Actually, I should clarify, in 4.6 it is no warning, this code is rejected outright with "error".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: It would have been easier if you had numbered all lines.

You are are using an old version of GCC that doesn't handle extern correctly. If you use a modern version, you'll see three issues with your code.

First, the local x in main() is not used (warning). Second, the static global x is not used (warning). Third, the external x is not defined(error).

Either you should not declare the global x static, or you should use ::x with no extern specification.

Comment: Do not know why this answer is getting up-votes. Neither does it give an answer for the questions nor is it respecting the meaning of the question asked!!

Comment: LinuxPenseur: I'll try to reformulate. 1. You think the extern x refers to the static x. This is not the case. The extern x is at program-scope, the static x at file-scope. These are different variables. Hence the first one is not defined and the later not used (hence the warning you have). That should answer your question. 2. In addition the lack of definition of the extern x should lead to a link error but doesn't in gcc 3.6 due to lack of conformance. And I won't go into the details, you should just use a modern compiler. If you still don't understand explain why in more details.

Comment: @ Antonie. I understand it now. Sorry if I were not nice with the comment.

Answer (score 2):

This code might compile, but it shouldn't link. The `extern int x;` declaration inside `main` tells the compiler to use some variable `x` whose location is defined externally (i.e., the `x` that has external linkage). There is no such variable! The file scope declaration `static int x = 6;` tells the compiler not to give this file scope `x` external linkage.

This program does not link with more recent versions of gcc (and also clang).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the compiler is actually complaining about the local `x` even though the message points to the `x` in the outer scope. It might be a compiler bug, which should be tested in a more recent version of gcc. In any case the error is not the warning itself, just the line number that it refers to.

Visual Studio 2010 does not generate any warnings at all unless I crank up the warning level to 4. Then it generates a warning on the local definition not the static one:

> warning C4189: 'x' : local variable is initialized but not referenced